# How to achieve word break in Bulma level component and set equal width to the left and right side?

Tags: css, flexbox, bulma

Hi I am having a problem with breaking words in Bulma's level component. It's not working. And I want to set the left and right level to an equal width. Actually I want it to act as a responsive table...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I somehow figured out the solution:

```
.level {
    .level-left {
        min-width: 0;
        word-break: break-word;
        flex-basis: 50%;

        .level-item {
            flex-shrink: 1;
        }
    }

    .level-right {
        min-width: 0;
        word-break: break-word;
        flex-basis: 50%;

        .level-item {
            flex-shrink: 1;
            text-align: right;
        }
    }
}
```

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/sasokovacic/pen/ZwyWVw)

Comment: Maybe, the level-item is intentionally designed not to break the word?